# Downloading BANKNIFTY data quantmod

Tags: r, web-scraping, quantmod

Quantmod can download stock data from both Yahoo and Google. I am trying to download the data for BANKNIFTY from google. This is index of banking stocks in the National Stock Exchange, India. R is able to download this data from Yahoo without any trouble (however the data are incomplete). Google has the [complete data](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3ABANKNIFTY&ei=76uDV9n9Eo-6ugSM7YzoCg).

However when I try to download, I get an error.

```
getSymbols("BankNifty",src="google")
#Error in download.file(paste(google.URL, "q=", Symbols.name,"&startdate=",  : 
#cannot open URL 'http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=BankNifty&startdate=Jan+01,+2007&enddate=Jul+11,+2016&output=csv'
```

`getSymbols("NSE:BankNifty",src="google")`
gives a similar error.

```
packageDescription("quantmod")$Version
[1] "0.4-5"

R version 3.3.0
```

(although the same error happens in other versions of R 3.2.2 )

How can I download the data using `quantmod` or an alternative package which will do the same.

Comment: You cannot download this data using `getSymbols` because there is no "Export to CSV" link on [the Google historical data page](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE%3ABANKNIFTY&ei=76uDV9n9Eo-6ugSM7YzoCg).

Comment: Ah! That explains it! I guess I will have scrape the page manually. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The correct symbol is "NSE:BANKNIFTY". But as Joshua Ulrich said:
You cannot download this data using getSymbols because there is no "Export to CSV" link on the Google historical data page.
You can only use web page parsing methods to get the data.